# git diff master..foo gives no output but foo is not merged

Tags: git

If a branch is not fully merged, shouldn't git diff give some output? How can the following behavior be explained:

```
$ git branch
foo
* master

$ git diff master..foo

$ git br -d foo
error: The branch 'foo' is not fully merged.
If you are sure you want to delete it, run 'git branch -D foo'.
```

So how can I find out what work has been done in foo that I have not yet merged into master?

Comment: Which version of git do you use, this works here as expected (GIT1.7.10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for the [`git show-branch` command](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show-branch.html).

`git show-branch master foo` will list all of the commits on *foo* that are not on *master*, and all of the commits on *master* that are not on *foo*.

The output format can be a little confusing at first, so it's worth reading the [output section of the man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show-branch.html#_output).

Answer (score 2):

```
git log master..foo
```

will show you all commits that are in foo but not in master.

Git diff itself will show you only differences in the actual tracked files, which is not the same as history. For example, foo may contain some changes which were later reversed.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible for two branches to be different but contain exactly the same content.  That's because there could be other differences, like different commit messages, time stamps, authors, etc., all of which contribute to the SHA1 hash that git uses to determine if the commits are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `git log` or (`git rev-list` if scripting) instead of diff to see the actual commits.

However, that being said, your diff command should have showed you differences unless you did the exact same work in the master as in foo since the common commit between the 2.

You can quickly see how all your branches are linked via

```
git --log --one-line --decorate --all
```

or

```
gitk --all
```

Otherwise, just specify who's history you want to see by replacing `--all` with `foo master` in the above examples.

once you

```
git merge foo
```

you will be able to

```
git branch -d foo
```